# Mapbox PlaceAutocomplete for android causes com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException

Tags: android, autocomplete, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm trying to use [Location Search](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/examples/global-location-search/) function provided by Mapbox  to allow my users to search for addresses and obtain the needed geolocation information (address text, LatLng, ecc).

I'm using and intent to start the requested feature with this code:

```
new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder()
            .accessToken(getString(R.string.mapbox_key))
            .placeOptions(
                    PlaceOptions.builder()
                    .limit(10)
                    .backgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(EditVideoActivity.this, R.color.colorWhite))
                    .hint("Search address...")
                    .build().build(EditVideoActivity.this);


startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
```

Whent I start searching for and address by start typing I get a toast with "Offline" message and error log with

> PlaceAutocompleteViewModel: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Array: {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79,37.5]}

What am I missing here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using Mapbox's Turf Java port? This seems to conflict.

Comment: Hi! I'v just imported in my android project this two
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.0.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v7:0.8.0'

Comment: Your places version looks wrong. This is what I current use:
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7:0.6.0'